# how to perform an extension of Random?

Tags: c#, algorithm, random

I was trying to implement an extension of Random class.

But this function will have one feature, you can get a number followed step. For example:

```
RandNumb(double min, double max, double step)
RandNumb(1, 10, 2) = 6
RandNumb(100, 1000, 500) = 1000
RandNumb(0.001, 0.1, 0.01) = 0.15
```

My first idea was to get a random number from min to max, and compare if this is a valid number (because of the step). If not, again generate another number.

But I'm sure that this is not a good performance. What do you think?

Comment: The valid values ​​for "RandNumb (1, 10, 2)" would not be 1, 3, 5, 7, 9?

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right.. sorry for that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition of the problem, it seems that the valid values ​​for "RandNumb (1, 10, 2)" would be: 1, 3, 5, 7, 9.

In that case. The code would look like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Random rd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RandNumb(rd, 1, 10, 2)=" + RandNumb(rd, 1, 10, 2));
            Console.WriteLine("RandNumb(rd, 100, 1000, 500)=" + RandNumb(rd, 100, 1000, 500));
            Console.WriteLine("RandNumb(rd, 0.001, 0.1, 0.01) =" + RandNumb(rd, 0.001, 0.1, 0.01)); 
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static double RandNumb(Random rd, double min, double max, double step)
    {
        int range = (int)Math.Floor((max - min) / step);
        int stepCount = rd.Next(0, range + 1);
        return min + (step * stepCount);
    }
}
```

And the result would look like this:

```
RandNumb(rd, 1, 10, 2)=3
RandNumb(rd, 100, 1000, 500)=600
RandNumb(rd, 0.001, 0.1, 0.01) =0,071
RandNumb(rd, 1, 10, 2)=5
RandNumb(rd, 100, 1000, 500)=600
RandNumb(rd, 0.001, 0.1, 0.01) =0,041
RandNumb(rd, 1, 10, 2)=3
RandNumb(rd, 100, 1000, 500)=600
RandNumb(rd, 0.001, 0.1, 0.01) =0,081
RandNumb(rd, 1, 10, 2)=9
RandNumb(rd, 100, 1000, 500)=600
RandNumb(rd, 0.001, 0.1, 0.01) =0,011
RandNumb(rd, 1, 10, 2)=7
RandNumb(rd, 100, 1000, 500)=100
RandNumb(rd, 0.001, 0.1, 0.01) =0,091
RandNumb(rd, 1, 10, 2)=5
RandNumb(rd, 100, 1000, 500)=100
RandNumb(rd, 0.001, 0.1, 0.01) =0,001
RandNumb(rd, 1, 10, 2)=1
RandNumb(rd, 100, 1000, 500)=600
RandNumb(rd, 0.001, 0.1, 0.01) =0,071
RandNumb(rd, 1, 10, 2)=1
RandNumb(rd, 100, 1000, 500)=600
RandNumb(rd, 0.001, 0.1, 0.01) =0,061
RandNumb(rd, 1, 10, 2)=5
RandNumb(rd, 100, 1000, 500)=100
RandNumb(rd, 0.001, 0.1, 0.01) =0,041
RandNumb(rd, 1, 10, 2)=3
RandNumb(rd, 100, 1000, 500)=600
RandNumb(rd, 0.001, 0.1, 0.01) =0,021
```

Answer (score 5):

Just generate the number from `min / step` to `max / step` and multiply generated result to `step`. In this case every result will be "valid".

And what's bad in your solution - is that there is a chance to never get "valid" number that is divided by step.

Answer (score 1):

How about this as a solution:

```
public static class RandomExtensions
{
    public static double RandNumb(
        this Random @this,
        double minimum, double maximum, double step)
    {
        var lowest = System.Math.Ceiling(minimum / step) * step;
        var highest = System.Math.Floor(maximum / step) * step;
        var numbers = (int)(1 + (highest - lowest) / step);
        var index = @this.Next(0, (int)numbers);
        return lowest + index * step;
    }
}
```

I tested against this code in LINQPad and it seemed to work fine.

```
var rnd = new Random();

rnd.RandNumb(1, 10, 2).Dump();
rnd.RandNumb(100, 1000, 500).Dump();
rnd.RandNumb(0.001, 0.1, 0.01).Dump();
rnd.RandNumb(7, 15, 3).Dump();
```

Here's a sample of my output:

```
4
1000
0.08
12
```